# How to attach sql server express database to project in entity framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-express

I create a sql server express database on local pc. I can access it successfully in a MVC Entity framework project using connection string as:

```
<add name="OTPTESTEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model3.csdl|res://*/Model3.ssdl|res://*/Model3.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ZHANG-PC\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=OTPTEST;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Now I want to send the project to another developer and think a way is do it is to attach the sql server express database to app_data folder of the project with connection string as

```
connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\...mdf
```

Is it right? But I can not locate the sql server express database which is created in Sql Management studio. I need help on how to do it. Thanks.

Comment: just ask him to try to connect his DB with entity framework then paste same connection string in your actual project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute this command in your **SQL Server Management Studio** to locate the physical database and it's log file location.

```
SELECT * FROM sys.database_files
```

Else

It you are running a 32-bit **SSMS** then you can find all database in following path.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS2014\MSSQL\DATA
```

Note: Before you copy the database you need to disconnect all connection in SMSS referring this database.